# finder search not showing thumbnails

Tags: finder, graphics, search

When I search filenames of images in Finder, using the box in the upper right corner, the result does not display the thumbnails, see attachment where I searched for 2015.
Otherwise the thumbnails display normally.
I have already deleted com.apple.finder.plist in Library/Preferences and relaunched Finder and in "Show View Options"  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>   the show icon preview box is ticked. In "Show View Options" I also modified the Icon Size, Grid Spacing and Text Size without success.

[image]

The images are associated to be opened by Preview in Get Info->Open with:. I do not have DropBox installed.
I am running MAC OS Mojave.
Do you have any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your view prefs  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  *within the search itself*.

It's possible to have the icon preview switched on for the folder you are about to search, yet off in the search itself. Each is remembered separately.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer but I have Show Icon preview ON also in the search result window.

Comment: Then I'm not sure. Do the previews show correctly before you enter the search?

Comment: Yes, in normal view thumbnails are visible, it is only in the Search view I have this problem.

Comment: Then idk what to suggest, sorry. The prefs are clearly stored separately, but idk where they're stored, unless it's in the .DS_Store file… but idk how you would find the DS file for a search.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to say that this is happening on an external USB hard disk, I do not know if this make a difference. And I do not see any .DS_Store file in the concerned directory, I have show invisible file option enabled

Comment: What format is the disk?  BTW, 'show all files' no longer shows DS_Store files in Finder, you have to find them from Terminal - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937352/unable-to-show-ds-store-file-on-mojave

Comment: The Disk is formatted MS-DOS Fat 32. Thank you for the link. I did not know it. Anyway in Terminal there is no .DS_Store in the directory

Comment: After your question about the formatting of the drive I attached a MAC OS Extended Journaled hard drive and with this the Search Window shows the thumbnails. So it seems that MS DOS FAT 32 formatted drives do not support this feature. Thank you for the hint